# Neo4j: Iterate through collection of relationships and set property to index

Tags: neo4j

In classic for(i etc.){ ... } style, I want to iterate through an ordered collection - pseudocode:

```
for n,i in nodes
  set node.weight = i + 1
end
```

Doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but not the prettiest thing:

```
MATCH ...
WITH COLLECT(something) AS nodes
FOREACH(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(nodes)) |
    FOREACH(node IN [nodes[i]] |
        SET node.weight = i + 1
))
```

Comment: Quite a hack to get that into neo4j.rb, but it works!

Comment: @Nicole White: Since this is not 'pretty,' does that mean these kinds of programming structures are purposefully not emphasised in Neo4j?